# iOS: adding buttons to Toolbar programmatically

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uitoolbar

I need to create Toolbar and add buttons programmatically. I will have different sets of buttons for diferent screens.

That's easy.

Also, I need to center those buttons. They should have equal space between them.

And also I need that all those buttons separate screen width only between themselfs. Like, I have 5 buttons, total screen width is 300, so each button will have width 60. I am not sure how to do that, i tried dirrenrt things but they wasn't centered or hadn't such width. Any ideas how to do that?

```
class OptionsView: UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!

var width: CGFloat {
    return 0//UIScreen.main.bounds.width/5 //was trying to calculate width , but it did not work
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
    toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any)
    toolbar.barTintColor = .white

    backgroundColor = .clear
}

func addAirPlay(target: Any?, action: Selector) {
    let normalImage = UIImage(named: "player-airplay")
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 100)
    button.setImage(normalImage, for: UIControlState())
    button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)

    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    //item.width = width //was trying to play with that
    var items = toolbar.items
    items?.append(item)
    toolbar.items = items
    toolbar.reload()
}

func addOrientation(target: Any?, action: Selector) {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.tag = orientationTag
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 100)
    button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)

    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    //item.width = width
    var items = toolbar.items
    items?.append(item)
    toolbar.items = items
    toolbar.reload()

    reloadOrientation()
}

func addFlexibleSpace() {
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var items = toolbar.items
    items?.append(item)
    toolbar.items = items
    toolbar.reload()
}
```

Creating:

```
    optionsView = OptionsView.loadFromNib()
    playerView.addSubview(optionsView)
    optionsView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.trailing.top.bottom.equalTo(self.optionsPlaceholderView)
    }
  // optionsView.addFlexibleSpace() //was trying that as well
    optionsView.addAirPlay(target: self, action: #selector(airplayButtonAction(_:)))
    optionsView.addFlexibleSpace()
    optionsView.addOrientation(target: self, action: #selector(orientationButtonAction(_:)))
    optionsView.addFlexibleSpace()
    optionsView.addFave(target: self, action: #selector(faveButtonAction(_:)))
    optionsView.addFlexibleSpace()
    optionsView.addExtra(target: self, action: #selector(showExtraButtonAction(_:)))
    optionsView.addFlexibleSpace()
    optionsView.addScenes(target: self, action: #selector(sceneButtonAction(_:)))
  //        optionsView.addFlexibleSpace()
```

Comment: Are you saying you want no space between any of the buttons and the buttons should fill the width of the screen?

Comment: @maddy, yes. I was unable to get that by code with some width settings. With 5 buttons, the one was never in the center of the screen

Comment: If you don't want spaces, don't add a flexible space between each. Why not create 5 `UIButton` and add them as subviews?

Comment: because buttons have different states, i am changing icons later

Comment: i was trying that. but they still was not centered

Comment: @maddy, with 5 items, fifth was never in the center of the screen...

Comment: @maddy, looks like I need to center UIButton in UIbarButtonItem....any ideas how can i do that?